# Efficient way to change the class of several matrices in R

Tags: r, class, matrix, numeric

I have several matrices and I would like to apply something like

`class(matrix) <- "numeric"` to all of them at once, i.e. the class of all matrices should be changed to numeric.

Do you know how to do this?

`dput(matrix[1:3,])` results in `structure(c(285.789361223578, 282.564165145159, 273.633228540421,  256.789452806115, 260.808130130172, 241.718192100525, 266.765343174338,  267.881099879742, 250.710165724158, 284.365977942944, 281.670583188534,  268.735618144274, 264.118778035045, 262.856532484293, 254.31867428124,  286.250801086426, 284.585711210966, 268.984649181366, 286.17267370224,  284.429456442595, 267.478255555034, 275.10055847466, 274.141056537628,  259.477523118258, 246.454664766788, 252.470473349094, 232.699362188578,  284.998321458697, 283.73363442719, 269.555955678225, 0, 0, 0), dim = c(3L,  11L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",  "", "", "vec")))`

Comment: How are your matrices structured, e.g. are they in a list, or just in the global environment?

Comment: I added some data information using dput

Comment: Your matrix already has columns of class "numeric", `Vectorize(\(x) class(mat[,x]))(1:ncol(mat))` `[1] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
 [8] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"`

Comment: Oh, yes you are rigtht, I forgot to reload the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this examples all matrix variables of the current environment are converted to numeric.
See the warning in the case where matrix cannot be converted to numeric.

```r
var1 <- matrix(1:10, 5, 2)
var2 <- matrix(as.character(5:13), 3,3)
var3 <- letters[1:5]
var4 <- matrix(letters[1])

print(sapply(mget(ls()), typeof))
#>        var1        var2        var3        var4 
#>   "integer" "character" "character" "character"

for (i in ls()[sapply(mget(ls()), is.matrix)])
  assign(i, as.numeric(get(i)))
#> Warning in assign(i, as.numeric(get(i))): NAs introduced by coercion

print(sapply(mget(ls()), typeof))
#>           i        var1        var2        var3        var4 
#> "character"    "double"    "double" "character"    "double"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is a nice idea, thank you!